# Extract terms, which are in a list, from text field in R

Tags: r, string, text, extract

I have a question regarding on string extraction.

I have a table below:

```
Text
Monday is windy and raining
Tuesday is sunny
Wednesday is snowing and cold
```

And I also have a list contains words:

```
windy
raining
sunny
snowing
cold
```

I want to extract terms in the list from table one:
So the result will be like:

```
Text                              Terms1      Terms2        Terms3
Monday is windy and raining       windy       raining
Tuesday is sunny                  sunny
Wednesday is snowing and cold     snowing     cold
```

Is there a way in R I can do it?

Thank you

Comment: you can create a `for` loop and use `if term %in% table` to select the terms to append. But you need to decide how the output will be stored, as a list of included terms with the text, or a list inserted in a cell of the table. Typically you do not want rows of varying lengths in a table which your above example has. Inserting all of the words into a single list in a cell gets around this

Comment: `term %in% table` won't work for searching for a string within a text, unless you split the text into a vector of separate words...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a vector of words:

```
> words
[1] "windy"   "raining" "sunny"   "snowing" "cold"
```

and a data frame with a `text` column:

```
> data
                           text
1   Monday is windy and raining
2              Tuesday is sunny
3 Wednesday is snowing and cold
```

You can easily create a matrix of true/false values for each word's presence in the text:

```
> sapply(words, function(w){grepl(w,data$text)})
     windy raining sunny snowing  cold
[1,]  TRUE    TRUE FALSE   FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE   FALSE FALSE    TRUE  TRUE
```

You can add this onto your data frame if you want:

```
> cbind(data, sapply(words, function(w){grepl(w,data$text)}))
                           text windy raining sunny snowing  cold
1   Monday is windy and raining  TRUE    TRUE FALSE   FALSE FALSE
2              Tuesday is sunny FALSE   FALSE  TRUE   FALSE FALSE
3 Wednesday is snowing and cold FALSE   FALSE FALSE    TRUE  TRUE
```

What you've given as the output you want looks like a very ragged data structure which might be correct to do as a list, but unless you can clarify that the code I've given should be enough for you to work this into whatever form you want with some basic R code. Look at the help for `grep` and friends to see how to search for strings within text.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
library(stringi)

Text <- c("Monday is windy and raining","Tuesday is sunny","Wednesday is snowing and cold")

terms <- c("windy","raining","sunny","snowing","cold")
terms_regex <- paste(terms,collapse="|")

stri_list2matrix(sapply(Text,function(x,terms_regex) str_extract_all(x,terms_regex),terms_regex),byrow=TRUE)
```